# Popup on datepicker

Tags: javascript

I have 3 dates: `Present, Start and End`.

```
Present = today's date
```

`Start` = any date but i am using past date for my question here

`End date` = (Present or Start) + number of payments.

If start date is null, end date is calculated based on Present date else it's calculated based on start date.

I have the following logic for remaining payment

```js
function PopulateEndDate() {
            var d2;
            var paymentDays;
            var stDate;
            var pDate;
        
            if (document.getElementById("startDate"))
                stDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
            if (document.getElementById("presentDate"))
                pDate = document.getElementById("presentDate").value;
                
                
            var futureSDate =  (pDate < stDate); //future start date
            var pastSDate = (pDate > stDate); //start date was in the past
            var sameDates = (pDate == stDate);
            
         
            
           
            if (stDate && futureSDate){
                d2 = new Date(stDate);
            }
            else if (stDate && sameDates){
                d2 = new Date(stDate);
            }
            else if (stDate && pastSDate){
                d2 = new Date(stDate);
                alert ("enter total number of payments");
            }
            else{
                d2 = new Date(pDate);
            }
            
            var dd = d2.getDate()+1000;
            var mm = d2.getMonth()+1;
            var yyyy = d2.getFullYear();
            var today = (mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy);

           
             var paymentDays = document.getElementById("paymentRemaining").value;
              
            if (paymentDays && paymentDays != "")
            //   d2.setMonth(d2.getMonth() + parseInt(paymentDays));
            var n = d2.getDate();
            d2.setDate(1);
            d2.setMonth(d2.getMonth() + parseInt(paymentDays));
            d2.setDate(Math.min(n, getDaysInMonth(d2.getFullYear(), d2.getMonth())));
            if (document.getElementById("endDate"))
                document.getElementById("endDate").value = getCurrentDay(d2);
        }


  function isLeapYear(year) {
            return (((year % 4 === 0) && (year % 100 !== 0)) || (year % 400 === 0));
        }
        function getDaysInMonth(year, month) {
            return [31, (isLeapYear(year) ? 29 : 28), 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31][month];
        }
        
         function getCurrentDay(date) {
            var dateOfToday;
            if(date && date != "")
                dateOfToday = new Date(date);
            else dateOfToday = new Date();

            var dd = ("0" + (dateOfToday.getDate())).slice(-2);
            var mm = ("0" + (dateOfToday.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
            var yyyy = dateOfToday.getFullYear();

            dateOfToday = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
            return dateOfToday;
        }
```

```html
<label>Present Value as of date</label> <input id="presentDate" name="presentDate" onchange="PopulateEndDate()" type="date"><br/><br/>
<label>Start of Lease </label> <input  id="startDate" onchange="PopulateEndDate()"  type="date" >
<br/>
<br/>
<label>Remaining Payments</label> <input id="paymentRemaining" name = "paymentRemaining" onchange="PopulateEndDate()" type="number" class="label1" style="text-align: right; width:80px;"> <br/><br/>
<label>End of Lease</label>  <input id="endDate" onchange="PopulateRentPaymentDates()" type="date" > <br/><br/>
```

Instead of an alert i want to add a popup only if user picks a date in the past. Is there a way to do that onclick of past date? I think the logic is something as follows. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

```
       function myPopUp() {
        var startDate = document.getElementById("startDate");
        var present = document.getElementById("presentDate");
        var pastLease = present > startDate;
        if(startDate && pastLease){
           //message goes here....
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your intention with the popup?  If it's to warn the user that the date is in the past, you could just disable past dates.

Comment: You could disable past dates by simply adding 'min' attribute to the input tag and specifying the date. Something like <input id="paymentRemaining" name = "paymentRemaining" min="2018-11-21" onchange="PopulateEndDate()" type="number" class="label1" style="text-align: right; width:80px;">

Comment: @devlincarnate I need the past date so i can't disable it but the popup basically lets the user know that they need to enter total number of payments.

Comment: @BambiOurLord I need the past dates.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple ways of doing it and it also depends on where and how you want to display the popup. Here's a simple example of how you could add a pop up on a click of a button.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("test");

btn.addEventListener( "click", function(){
 if ( document.getElementById("popup") ) {
   document.getElementById("popup").style.display = "block";
  }
});
```

```css
#popup {
  display: none; 
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

#popupMessage {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="popup">
   <p id="popupMessage"> Your Popup Message</p>
</div>

<button id="test"> Popup</button>
```

In your case you could add the `myPopUp()`function to date field which you want to be triggering the function. Then once the condition is met you could dynamically create DOM elements which will act as your pop up which can then also be appended to any other element in your markup code. Here is a simple example of what I described above.

```js
let condition = false;

let btn = document.getElementById("popupBtn");

btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
  //set some condition to true on button click
  condition = true;

  //if condition is true then add the popup
    if ( condition ) {
    //create container
    let popupContainer = document.createElement("DIV");
    //add popupContainer class to the container
    popupContainer.setAttribute("class", "popupContainer");

    //create popup text
    let popupText = document.createElement("P");
    popupText.setAttribute("class", "popupMessage");
    //add popup text
    popupText.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Your Popup Message") );

    //add the popupText to popupContainer
    popupContainer.appendChild( popupText );


    //add the popup above p element with id popupAboveThisElement
    if ( document.getElementById("popupAboveThisElement") ) {
      document.getElementById("popupAboveThisElement").parentNode.insertBefore( popupContainer, document.getElementById("popupAboveThisElement") );
    }
 }//end if condition true
});
```

```css
.popupContainer {
  display: block; 
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border-radius: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}

.popupMessage {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1> A title </h1>

<p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ea, mollitia dolorem repellat tenetur, et eligendi, ipsam consequuntur debitis temporibus laboriosam ducimus harum fuga, quae ipsa.</p>

<p id="popupAboveThisElement"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi, quis, nihil modi fuga debitis error delectus itaque est illum velit in aliquam deserunt ipsum, non cupiditate, alias consectetur. Saepe, deleniti, aliquid. Fugiat sit, iste, tempore optio nam dolorum alias maxime quam numquam autem aspernatur porro beatae. Fugiat saepe doloremque facere!</p>

<button id="popupBtn"> Display Popup</button>
```

I hope this is of help to you.

Comment: If someone down-votes, could you please at least leave a comment as to why it was down-voted so that I may improve the answer ?